# Relative cursor based pagination not working in Shopify api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have implemented Relative cursor-based pagination in my Shopify app using shopify_api gem.

Here is the code I have implemented

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 50 })
product_list = []
while products.next_page?
  products = products.fetch_next_page
  product_list << products
end
product_list
```

But it is giving me an error on the **next_page?** and **fetch_next_page** like https://prnt.sc/q95sjp

```
My Shopify API gem version is "shopify_api (8.0.0)"      
Used shopify api version: 2019-10                                   
rails: 5.2.3         
shopify_app: 10.0.0
```

Any insight?

Comment: can you double check your shopify_api version, e.g.` bundle show shopify_api` or `bundle info shopify_api` i think new pagination works in v 8.0.0 >

Comment: For some reason, it's using Kaminari (according to the error you no the picture you linked). Is there any wrapper of the Shopify gem that use kaminari in your code?